# How to define a new d-bus interface that can be introspected?

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I've created a custom d-bus service which seems to be registered and can be activated by a dbus call, however it has no interface definition and can not be introspected by tools like d-feet.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, I've created the following interface file:

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC
    "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd" >
<node xmlns:doc="http://www.freedesktop.org/dbus/1.0/doc.dtd">
  <interface name="com.me.test.Manager">
    <method name="Start">
      <arg name="name" direction="in" type="s">
        <doc:doc><doc:summary>Name of new contact</doc:summary></doc:doc>
      </arg>
      <arg name="email" direction="in" type="s">
        <doc:doc><doc:summary>E-mail address of new contact</doc:summary></doc:doc>
      </arg>
      <arg name="id" direction="out" type="u">
        <doc:doc><doc:summary>ID of newly added contact</doc:summary></doc:doc>
      </arg>
      <doc:doc>
        <doc:description>
          <doc:para>
            Adds a new contact to the address book with their name and
            e-mail address.
          </doc:para>
        </doc:description>
      </doc:doc>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

I've named the file this:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces/com.me.test.Manager.xml
```

However I still do not see any object on the session bus when I search for "com.me.test" using d-feet browser. How does this interface actually get registered by dbus, does dbus monitor this directory? I've tried restarting dbus but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your service need to call [org.freedesktop.DBus.RequestName](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-names) to be visible under ceertain name and after that respond to [org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-introspectable) requests

Here is example how I implemented it in my dbus library - https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/lib/stdifaces.js#L24-L92